# How to write a query to find values /data in one table, in different rows

Tags: sql

Table

```
Customer  Account No  Product  Transaction      Amount         Date        Transaction ID
001       10000200     215        Debit           100,000.00   01/01/2021   20001
003       20000000     217        Credit          100,000.00   01/01/2021   20001
002       30000000     212        Debit           5,000,000.00 02/02/2021   50001
004       50000000     217        Credit          5,000,000.00 02/02/2021   50001
```

I need to get summary report of customers fund transfers with Debited/Credited account for 217 product?

Summary need to be like this:

```
Date           Customer  Account No  Product  Transaction  Debited Account    Product(Debited)      Amount 
01/01/2021     003      20000000     217     Credit            10000200       215               100,000.00
02/02/2021     004      50000000     217     Credit            30000000       212             5,000,000.00
```

Comment: How are you identifying that amount debiting from Product 217 and getting credited to Product 215 & 212.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai it looks like maybe by transaction id? (but I'll let OP confirm this first)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all in pairs

```
SELECT 
C.Date,C.Customer,C.[Account No],C.Product,C.Transaction,D.[Account No],D.[Product] as [Product(Debited)],C.Amount

FROM (SELECT * FROM [OrignTable] WHERE transaction = 'Credit') C 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [OrignTable] WHERE transaction = 'Debit') D ON C.[Transaction ID] = D.[Transaction ID]
WHERE C.PRODUCT = '217'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Date , Customer,  Account ,  Product,  Transaction,  Debited Account,
(select product from TABLE_NAME where transaction = 'Credit') as Product(Debited), Amount   
WHERE Product = 217;
```

Something like this should work too.